# Best way to retrieve metadata without affecting source tracking?

Tags: salesforcedx

To set up for development work, I create a scratch org and push in metadata stored in a github repo.

I find that after I have completed a piece of work (or part way through), I may have changed some metadata remotely (i.e. via the Salesforce UI), which I then want to pull into my local code base.

My process is:

- run `sfdx force:source:status` to determine what metadata I have changed remotely.
- then use `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m SomeMetadataType:MetadataName` to get that metadata from the org into my local source code.

However, once I have used the retrieve command, if I try to save again I am always prevented by a number of conflict messages. The only way I can resolve this is to either create a new scratch org, which takes a lot of time, or do a `sfdx force:source:push -f` to force push the metadata. Again this takes a lot of time.

Is there a way I can retrieve metadata from an org, but avoid these conflict errors and maintain the source tracking?

Comment: Use pull instead of retrieve. You are mixing the commands inappropriately. The retrieve is NOT updating tracking status and hence your conflicts.

Comment: Hi Phil. Thanks for your comment. Yes, I should have said that I was specifically using `force:source:retrieve` because it has a `-m` flag allow a specific piece of metadata to be pulled back. Whereas `force:source:pull` doesn't have that option, so I get a large amount of other metadata that I then have to remove from my local code base before commiting.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `force:source:pull` and `force:source:push` to ensure tracking status is maintained in both directions.